# RuntimeError: Gradients aren't CUDA tensors

Tags: pytorch

I am getting the following error.

```
File "/net/if5/wua4nw/wasi/academic/research_with_prof_chang/projects/question_answering/duplicate_question_detection/source/train.py", line 62, in train
    loss.backward()
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/autograd/variable.py", line 145, in backward
    self._execution_engine.run_backward((self,), (gradient,), retain_variables)
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/autograd/function.py", line 208, in _do_backward
    result = super(NestedIOFunction, self)._do_backward(gradients, retain_variables)
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/autograd/function.py", line 216, in backward
    result = self.backward_extended(*nested_gradients)
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/_functions/rnn.py", line 210, in backward_extended
    grad_hx)
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/backends/cudnn/rnn.py", line 360, in backward_grad
    raise RuntimeError('Gradients aren\'t CUDA tensors')
RuntimeError: Gradients aren't CUDA tensors
```

while running `loss.backward()` in pytorch. Forward propagation is working fine but when the backpropagation step executes, I am getting the error. Can anyone suggest me how to solve the problem?

P.S: I am not posting the source code since its too long!

Comment: could you post the relevant code snippet that gave you this error. Just show what you've got in `train.py` up to the line (62) where it gave the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch RuntimeError : Gradients are not CUDA tensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206561/pytorch-runtimeerror-gradients-are-not-cuda-tensors)